# Unable to import test results to jira via rest api

Tags: rest, jira

i'm using the following curl command to import the output.xml file into jira test execution key and receiving error as below. I'm sure the test execution key is existing in jira and the project id is also correct. Any pointers?

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u userid:pass -F "file=@output.xml" "https://server/rest/raven/latest/import/execution/robot?projectKey=PROJKEY+and+testExecKey=TESTEXNKEY" -o error.txt
```

The error i receive is as below

```
The User "userid" does not have permission to create issues
```

Why does it try to create new issue while the issue already exists? And why does it say the user doesn't have access when the access is there?

Comment: this works fine when i dont include project key and only just execution key.  `curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u userid:pass -F "file=@output.xml" "https://server/rest/raven/latest/import/execution/robot?testExecKey=TESTEXNKEY" -o error.txt `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean Xray add-on and you probably use the same request [per their documentation](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResults-REST-RobotFrameworkXMLresults). The problem seems to be with your parameter syntax. It should be `.../robot/?projectKey=PROJKEY&testExecKey=TESTEXNKEY` (i.e. `&` instead of `+and+`).

Plus I would explicitly specify it's a POST request: `curl -X POST ...`.

But their error message is not clear, anyway. I don't have Xray available right now, but if you keep having troubles, I would recommend checking with their support.

Comment: yeah, when i replaced the `+and+` with `&` it worked like a charm. i didnt include the `-X POST` though.